# How to return an empty jsx element from the render function in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I have a code in `react` that looks something like this:

```js
class UserManagement extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            users: undefined,
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        // load the users state with a Promise
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.setState({users: []});
        }, 800);
    }

    render() {
        if ( this.state.users === undefined ) {
            // until the users state is updated, I want to return an empty element
            return null;
        }

        // real site rendering
        return <div>We have users</div>;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <UserManagement />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div>Will be blank at first while we don't have users, then show "We have users" after 800ms when we have users</div>
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

My question is: How to return an empty element until the users state is returned? I tried to return `(null)` as suggested in some places, but the browser raise this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

I am aware of the option to return `(<div></div>)`, but I am not sure that this is the best practice in this case.

Thnaks!

Comment: @Rajesh throws the same error as `(null)`

Comment: The React docs [say you should be able to return `null`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html#preventing-component-from-rendering), so it's strange this isn't working.

Comment: Returning `null` works just fine.  Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) demonstrating the problem with doing that. Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: My apologies. Rushed to comment. Are you manipulating the style of this component anywhere else

Comment: Actually, I've added the snippet for you. Works a treat. Please update it to demonstrate the problem you're having.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder My bet is OP is manipulating the style property of this component somewhere in the code. All OP needs is to add a check before doing it

Comment: @Rajesh: It'll be something along those lines, yeah. :-) Until they update, we can't answer the question properly.

Comment: I have an error in my code and now it's working.... this code works just fine, it's my fault...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think just add `{ null }` not `null`, in your section to show empty component.

Have you tried it already ?

Answer (score 33):

Just in case anyone want another approach:

Since React v16.2 you can use [Fragments](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html) allowing to add an empty JSX tag like this:

```
  return (
    <>
      <ChildA />
      <ChildB />
      <ChildC />
    </>
  );
```

Example extracted from official docs.

So in your case, returning a Fragment without any childs, works.

```
  return <></>;
```

Comment: Know how I can add an attribute to the empty tag? i.e., add a key if it's in a loop ?

Comment: To add a prop (attribute) to a Fragment just use the "long version" of it: `<React.Fragment key="...">...<React.Fragment>`

Answer (score 9):

You need to wrap it in a `React.Fragment` tag.

```
<React.Fragment></React.Fragment>
```

Comment: Please consider adding some form of explanation or more detail to your answer. Code only answers are typically discouraged.

Answer (score 7):

Ok so as Facebook [says](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/07/17/react-v0.11.html#rendering-to-null) :

> Since React's release, people have been using work arounds to "render
>   nothing". Usually this means returning an empty  or .
>   Some people even got clever and started returning  to avoid
>   extraneous DOM nodes. We finally provided a "blessed" solution that
>   allows developers to write meaningful code. Returning null is an
>   explicit indication to React that you do not want anything rendered.
>   Behind the scenes we make this work with a  element, though
>   in the future we hope to not put anything in the document. In the mean
>   time,  elements do not affect layout in any way, so you can
>   feel safe using null today!

Answer (score 1):

use the react Fragment <></>. One of its advantages is that it does not create additional Dom nodes into rendered component (such as an empty div tag).

You can use ternary condition to make your code more readable.

```
    render() {
        ( this.state.users === undefined ) ?
            return <></>   
        : return <div>We have users</div>;
    }
```

or oven simpler syntax would be

```
    render() {
        ( this.state.users) ?
            return <div>We have users</div>  
        : return <></>;
    }
```

Comment: This won't work. `return` is a [statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return), whereas the ternary operator wants an [expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators). You should `return` the whole `ternary` expression and remove the `return`s from the inside

Comment: you should try it . Please check conditionnal rendering in react official page https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html. Just instead of "if else" , I used ternary condition

Comment: The difference is that `if` and `else` take statements whereas the ternary takes an expression

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add ternary operators like:

```
this.state.users? return null : return <div>We have user<\div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I did using React.useState was to initialize an empty JSX.Element object like so

```
const [jsxObject, setJsxObject] = React.useState(<></>);
```

Then, in whatever function you want to return a JSX.Element

```
setJsxObject(<h1>whatever inside</h1>);
```

Render it in the component

```
{jsxObject}
```